# How To Set The Language of The Subtitles in Tales from the Borderlands

Tags: tales-from-the-borderlands

I bought "Tales from the Borderlands" just yesterday. There was an update today and now suddenly the subtitles are German with no visible option to change them to any other language.

I checked the "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Telltale Games\Borderlands.exe" path in the system registry, but the field with the key "language" has the value "english". I was even frustrated enough to delete all files with German in the name from the *archives* folder, but the menu and the subtitles stayed German.

Does anyone know how to set the language of the subtitles?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem, and found help from this thread :

https://steamcommunity.com/app/330830/discussions/0/368542585860436705/

On Win7, changing the "Language for non-Unicode Programs" under "Region and Language" helped. The same should work also with Win10, but I couldn't verify it myself. Please note that this solution does potentially also affect other programs, so they might have their language changed as well.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/182090)

Comment: I you insist.. 
On Win7, changing the 'Language for non-Unicode Programs' under 'Region and Language' helped.. Seems the same should work also with Win10, but I couldn't verify it myself.

Please note that this solution does potentially also affect other programs, so they might have their language changed as well.

Comment: Comments are temporary, I [edit]ed this into your answer. Also, I just now saw that you're new to the site. Welcome! Take the [tour] if you haven't already :)

Comment: I had the same problem with another Telltale game, Minecraft: Story Mode. It seems with a certain update they chose to enforce whatever language the system is configured to by default.

Answer (score 1):

I also had the same problem today. Try changing your locale in control panel to English. Check this link for more details.

http://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=543348020

Comment: I don't know where the game gets the language settings, but changing the language of Windows 10 does not work.

Comment: @SteffiS. This not about Windows display language. The setting should be called something like "language for non-Unicode programs" or "system locale", and require a restart when changing, IIRC.

Answer (score -1):

I suppose you play via steam. There are some game options available sthrough the steam app including language ([see](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TTherti4rgg) ).  From there you can set also command line options for the launch in case your language isn't there.